# unable to recognize file. connection refused

Tags: command-line, files, iptables, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

On an Amazon Linux 2 instance, the command line is throwing the following `connection refused` error every time a command is run that references a file path.  The same error is thrown when an `https` url is used in place of the file path.

**Why is this happening, and how can this problem be remediated so that the file can be read and used from the command line?**

Here is the console output:

```
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$ sudo kubectl apply -f rbac-kdd.yaml | tee kubeadm-rbac-kdd.out
unable to recognize "rbac-kdd.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
unable to recognize "rbac-kdd.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$
```

The relative path of the file is correct.  The command is trying to apply calico to a Kubernetes cluster created by `kubeadm`, if that helps.  **But I am thinking this is a basic linux question.**

SELinux has been disabled on this Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance.

Would appreciate some pointers on this as I try to identify possible causes.

---

**PROBLEM ISOLATED:**

---

Also, the contents of `.kube/config` indicate port `6443` as follows:

```
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$ cat /home/kubernetes-host/.kube/config
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <encrypted-certificate-authority-data-here>
    server: https://ip-of-ec2-instance:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: <encrypted-client-certificate-data-here>
    client-key-data: <encrypted-client-key-data-here>
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$
```

**The problem seems to be that the `kubectl apply` command is using port `8080` while the Kubernetes apiserver is using port `6443`.  How can this mismatch be remediated so that the `kubectl apply` command uses port `6443`?**

Further, `kubectl` is able to see that `6443` is the correct port, and `curl` can reach the correct `6443` port, as follows:

```
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://ip-of-ec2-instance:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://ip-of-ec2-instance:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy  

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$ curl https://ip-of-ec2-instance:6443
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$

[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$ curl https://127.0.0.1:6443
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
[kubernetes-host@ip-of-ec2-instance ~]$
```

**Why is `kubectl apply` NOT able to map to port `6443`, when `kubectl cluster-info` is able to map to the correct port?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you can't connect to the Kubernetes API server. This could be for many reasons

- The kubernetes API server is not running
- The API server is not listening on TCP/8080
- The API server is not listening on the loopback address of 127.0.0.1
- The API server is not listening with HTTP (but with HTTPS)
- A local firewall (such as iptables) is blocking the connection
- TCPwrapper is blocking the connection.
- A mandatory access control system such as SELinux is blocking the connection, but you said this was disabled. And if you have AppArmor installed on Amazon Linux, then I don't know if anyone can help you. :)
- and this list can go on to many more esoteric reasons why this connection won't happen.

some remediation/troubleshooting steps

- Make sure the k8s api server is running (I don't know how you've installed it, so I can't suggest how you'd check, probably with `systemctl status` or `docker ps`).
- Run `ss -ln` and check for something listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 or *:8080
- see if you can connect to the socket with something else `curl -k https://127.0.0.1:8080` to check https, or `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080` for HTTP.
- If your API server is running in a docker container, make sure it's listening on 8080 on the host. `docker ps` or `docker inspect` to see the port forwarding.
- Check the firewall, `iptables -S`, this is a longshot, not often will you see rules blocking packets going to localhost.
- Check /etc/hosts.deny for anything that might stop you (again, this is a long shot, because this doesn't usually get configured by accident).

#### Edit

After seeing some more of your troubleshooting data. I noticed that you're running `kubectl` as root. And your kubeconfig is in a user directory. You should run the kubectl as the user "kubernetes-host" by just dropping the `sudo` at the beginning of your command. The kubeconfig file will direct Kubectl to the right endpoint (address and port), but running as root, kubectl will not check in /home/kubernetes-host/.kube/config.

So try `kubectl apply -f rbac-kdd.yaml`

If you have to run as root for some reason, you should:

1) Question the life choices that lead you here.

2) run `sudo kubectl apply --kubeconfig=/home/kubernetes-host/.kube/config -f rbac-kdd.yaml` to explicitly use the config in the kubernetes-host user's home directory.

Comment: I put the results of your suggestions at the end of the OP.  Looks like port 8080 is not mapping.  Any suggestions?  I am using kubeadm to create the kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I have isolated the problem further with what I just added to the end of the OP.

Comment: I just added more output indicating that `kubectl` is able to see that port `6443` is correct, even though the error is due to `kubectl apply` using port `8080` instead.  Any ideas about how the problem can be further isolated or resolved from this point?

Comment: I think it might be due to you running as root in the example. Try dropping the 'sudo' from your ```kubectl apply``` command.

Comment: That might have resolved the problem.  My immediate removal of `sudo` just now resulted in the command processing successfully.  But why?

Comment: when you run as sudo. Kubectl is running as the root user. Kubectl checks the home directory under .kube/config to get its configuration, when it's running as root, it's checking under /root/.kube/config because root's home directory is /root.